# Landscape ask for "At least three machines with more than one disk"

Tags: landscape

I'm currently plaing on a Proof of Concept about Ubuntu OpenStack, after some battle with landscape I continue to see that it ask for 3 servers but I have 3 of that with 2 disks and 2 NICs.
What's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the screenshot, you only have **two** servers available in MAAS. The first one "creamy-scent.maas" is already used, (probably this is where Landscape itself is deployed?).

You need at least three which are in the *Ready* state in MAAS.